# About class and __str__

Tags: python, string, class

I try to return a string value when i print an instance of my class. It seems like that shouldn't work like i wish.

```py
class oObject (object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

new = oObject(50)
# if I use print it's Okay
print new
# But if i try to do something like that ...
print new + '.kine'
```

Comment: Use `print str(new)+'.kine'`, Python doesn't coerce objects to string when concatenating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override `__add__` for it:

```
class oObject (object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
    def __add__(self,val):
        return str(self.value)+val

new = oObject(50)
'''if I use print it's Okay'''
print new
'''But if i try to do something like that ...'''
print new + '.kine'   #prints 50.kine
```

Comment: Rather a lot of overkill, don't you think? Python doesn't coerce automatically for other objects, better use an explicit `str()` call on the instance.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes it is, **but** if he wants to convert this to string **implicitly** then it's good.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: That's fine ! I work with an API who returns a lot of strings, and it's very borring to convert my value each time. But maybe i'm wrong ?

Comment: @MObject if you're using the object witeh `+` at too many places in your code then `__add__` is good, otherwis if it appears only few times then it's better to be **explicit**.

Comment: `__repr__` seems to be unnecessary here.

Answer (score 3):

Try explicitly converting to a string:

```
print str(new) + '.kine'
```

Alternatively you could use a format string:

```
print '{}.kine'.format(new)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python converts the result of the whole expression to a string before printing, not individual items. Convert your object instance to a string before concatenating:

```
print str(new) + '.kine'
```

Python is a strongly typed language and won't convert items to strings automatically when using operators like the '+' sign.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print new` to see that your `.__str__()` definition works.  The `print` calls it internally.  However, the `+` operator does not use the implicit conversion to string.